# How to respond to a question with adjective, which has negative meaning (e.g. unrelated, unnecessary, inconvenient)

Tags: meaning, adjectives, negation

If someone ask me "Was it inconvenient to you?", and it was inconvenient to me, which answer is correct?

1. Yes, it was inconvenient to me.
2. No, it was inconvenient to me.

On the other hand, I was actually free to talk, what should I say?

1. Yes, it was actually convenient. Sorry for missed your call.
2. No, it was actually convenient. Sorry for missed your call.

Comment: I don't think you are asking the question that you intend to ask. The second part seems to have context that the first does not, although it is still unclear. Could you explain the context, please?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. See also: [ell.se] Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence

> Was it inconvenient to you?

Is a question, so if you agree, you would answer

> Yes, it was inconvenient for me.

If it was not the case, you would answer

> No, it was actually convenient.

Note that I changed "to me" to "for me", similarly in the question:

> Was it inconvenient for you?

Answer (score 0):

Since "Was it inconvenient to you?" is a simple direct question, the answer "Yes" or "No" will suffice:

- "Yes." (You are correct.)
- "No." (You are incorrect.)

We can make the replies more informative:

- "Yes, it was inconvenient. I was busy doing something else."
- "No, it wasn't inconvenient. I just couldn't be bothered to pick up the phone."

Or:

- "No, it was convenient. I wasn't doing anything at the time."

---

Loaded questions are more tricky to answer, since neither "Yes" nor "No" will do: The question:

- "Are you still beating your wife?"

cannot really be answered with "Yes" or "No", since:

- "Yes." can be interpreted as "I no longer beat my wife."
- "No." can be interpreted as "I am still beating my wife."

In this case, a rebuttal is needed:

- "I have never beaten my wife."

Unless, of course you do beat your wife.